# Short exact sequences of finite abelian groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, abelian-groups, exact-sequence

I was reading [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/61817/determining-whether-there-is-a-short-exact-sequence), and I was wondering if you had instead the direct sums as such:

$$0\rightarrow\mathbb{Z}_{p^{a_1}}\oplus...\oplus\mathbb{Z}_{p^{a_n}}\rightarrow\mathbb{Z}_{p^{b_1}}\oplus...\oplus\mathbb{Z}_{p^{b_n}}\rightarrow\mathbb{Z}_{p^{c_1}}\oplus...\oplus\mathbb{Z}_{p^{c_n}}\rightarrow0,$$

you could still reach similar conclusions that $\sum b_i=\sum a_i+\sum c_i$ and $b_1\leq a_1+c_1$, like how the answer in the link would have instead that $j+(m+n-j)=m+n$ and  $j\leq m+n$. If this is true, could it be proved similarly?

Comment: First, yes, just by size considerations. Second, you’d need to be a bit more careful about describing your map, because as written you have no warrant fo assuming the embedding respects components.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Sorry, could you clarify a bit more what you mean by size considerations, and how I would need to be more careful? I am definitely having difficulty extending the original proof to this problem.

Comment: If $0\to A\to B\to C\to 0$ is a short exact sequence, with all groups finite, then $|B|=|A||C|$. So in your case, $p^{b_1+\cdots+b_n}=p^{a_1+\cdots+a_n}p^{c_1+\cdots+c_n}$, which gives the equality of sums you want.

Comment: As to “being more careful”, that means that what you want to establish is *false* without more information about **exactly** what your maps are.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin I see, the equality is obvious from Lagrange. Would the inequality be true then if the $a_i$ were decreasing? I suppose I am mainly having difficulty figuring out how to conclude anything about $a_1, b_1, c_1$ alone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To take this out of the comment section.

The answer to your first question is “yes”. This is because if
$$1 \to A\to B \to C\to 1$$
is an exact sequence of groups (using multiplicative notation for generality as this does not require groups to be abelian, hence the use of $1$ instead of $0$), this implies that $B$ contains a normal subgroup $M\triangleleft B$ such that $A\cong M$ and $B/M\cong C$. In particular, if at least two of the groups in question are finite then so is the third, and $|B|=|A||C|$. This gives the equality you have.

The answer to your second question is “not as stated, at any rate.”

This is because you are not saying anything about the maps. Even if you assume the groups are given in “ascending order”, that is, with $x_1\leq x_2\leq\cdots\leq x_n$ (where $x$ stands for either $a$, $b$, or $c$), you cannot simply assume that the maps you have will respect the decomposition.

To give an explicit example, consider
$$ 0 \to \mathbb{Z}_3\oplus\mathbb{Z}_9 \stackrel{f}{\to} \mathbb{Z}_{27}\oplus\mathbb{Z}_{27} \stackrel{g}{\to}\mathbb{Z}_3\oplus\mathbb{Z}_9\to 0$$
where the maps are given as follows:

- $f(a,b) = (3b,9a)$.
- $g(x,y) = (x\bmod 3,y\bmod 9)$.

These are morphisms, as is easy to verify; $f$ is one-to-one, since $(3b,9a)=(0,0)$ implies that $9|b$ and $3|a$, hence $(a,b)=(0,0)$ in $\mathbb{Z})3\oplus\mathbb{Z}_{27}$; $g$ is clearly surjective. The composition $g\circ f$ is zero, since $g(f(a,b)) = g(3b,9a) = (3b\bmod 3,9a\bmod 9) = (0,0)$. Thus, $\mathrm{Im}(f)\subseteq \mathrm{ker}(g)$.

Finally, if $(x,y)\in\mathrm{ker}(g)$, then $3|x$ and $9|y$, so we can write $x=3x’$, $y=9y’$, and $0\leq x’\lt 9$, $0\leq y’\lt 3$; hence $(x,y)=f(y’,x’)$. Thus, $\mathrm{ker}(g)=\mathrm{Im}(f)$, proving that the sequence is exact.

However, $b_1=3$, $a_1=c_1=1$, so $b_1\not\leq a_1+c_1$.  Thus, the requested inequality *does not hold*.

The problem is that even if you require that the summands be listed in ascending order of size, there is nothing structural that requires the maps $f$ and $g$ to respect the coordinate order.

That’s why you can’t seem to extend the argument: because it’s false. You *cannot* conclude the stuff you want about $a_1,b_1,c_1$ themselves just from knowing you have an exact sequence.

---

Now, it looks like you just decided to [repost this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3683675/short-exact-sequences-of-direct-sums-of-mathbbz-pn) but adding the condition that the summands go in *descending* order, so the example above does not work for that condition.

Under that condition, the inequality *does* hold. To see this, note that if $A=\mathbb{Z}_{p^{a_1}}\oplus\cdots\oplus\mathbb{Z}_{p^{a_n}}$, $B=\mathbb{Z}_{p^{b_1}}\oplus\cdots\oplus\mathbb{Z}_{p^{b_m}}$, and  $C=\mathbb{Z}_{p^{c_1}}\oplus\cdots\oplus\mathbb{Z}_{p^{c_k}}$, with $a_1\geq\cdots\geq a_n$, $b_1\geq \cdots \geq b_m$, $c_1\geq \cdots \geq c_k$, and
$$ 0 \to A\to B\to C\to 0$$
is an exact sequence (note here we do not even require the same number of summands in each of the groups), then the exponent of $A$ is $p^{a_1}$, the exponent of $B$ is $p^{b_1}$, and the exponent of $C$ is $p^{c_1}$ (the exponent being the smallest positive integer $r$ such that $rx=0$ for every $x$ in the group; and in these cases, there is an element that achieves the bound). In particular, if $x\in B$, then $p^{c_1}x$ must map to the trivial element in $C$, and therefore must be in the image of $A$; in particular, $p^{a_1}(p^{c_1}x)=0$, because every element of $A$ is of exponent $p^{a_1}$. Thus, $p^{a_1+c_1}x=0$ for all $x\in B$, which means that $p^{b_1}\leq p^{a_1+c_1}$, and hence $b_1\leq a_1+c_1$.

Comment: So sorry, I shouldn't have reposted the question. It's not a good excuse at all, but I'm fairly new to all this. Thanks so much for your detailed answer and for also for preventing me from doing stupid stuff (like reposting questions) in the future! (Also, I did originally intend them to be decreasing, as I said in latest comment above. So sorry!!!)