# Show that $\mathbb{Z}_4\rightarrow \mathbb{Z}_8\oplus \mathbb{Z}_2\rightarrow \mathbb{Z}_4$ is exact

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-topology

I want to know whether $0\rightarrow \mathbb{Z}_4\stackrel{f}\rightarrow \mathbb{Z}_8\oplus \mathbb{Z}_2\rightarrow \mathbb{Z}_4\rightarrow 0$ is exact wrt group homomorphism under addition.

Since $\mathbb{Z}_2^2\neq \mathbb{Z}_4$, so $$ f(1)=(x,1) $$

Since $\mathbb{Z}_4$ is cyclic of order $4$, so $$ 4x=0,\ kx\neq 0\ (1\leq k\leq 3)$$

Hence $x=2$ or $ 6$ so that $$ {\rm image}\ f = \{ (2,1),\ (4,0),\ (6,1),\ (0,0)\}$$
(That is, image of $f$ is unique)

Hence by direct computation, $$ (\mathbb{Z}_8\oplus \mathbb{Z}_2)/f(\mathbb{Z}_4) = ((1,1)) = \{ (0,0),\ (1,1),\ (2,0),\ (3,1) \} $$
Here element is a representative. That is $(1,1)$ is corresponded to $\{ (1,1),\ (3,0),\ (5,1),\ (7,0) \}$, whose order is $4$.

Hence it is exact. Here we have a question :

Question : To prove this, we must compute directly ? Does there exists more systematic way ? Thank you in anticipation.

Comment: This problem is discussed in these two questions: [1](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/61817), [2](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/42434).

Comment: I see no reason why $f(1)$ cannot be $(2,0)$, which does not lead to an exact sequence. There is more than one cyclic subgroup of order $4$ in $\Bbb Z_8 \oplus \Bbb Z_2$, you have to pick "the right one".

Comment: If $f(1)=(x,0)$ then $$(\mathbb{Z}_8\oplus \mathbb{Z}_2)/{\rm image}\ f = \mathbb{Z}_2^2$$